# Understanding how to use list.count() when appending Class objects to a list

Tags: python

I have an issue whenever I try to use `list.count()` on a list that has objects appended to it.

An example of my code is as follows:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, Name, Age, Gender):
        self.Name = Name
        self.Age = Age
        self.Gender = Gender

personlist = [Person("Joan", 15, "F"), 
        Person("Henry", 18, "M"), 
        Person("Marg", 21, "F")]

print(list.count(personlist))
```

Everytime I try this, I get

```
TypeError: list.count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

Can someone explain to me why python sees 0 arguments given when there are 3 objects in the list?

Comment: Also what are you trying to do with count? Currently your code will give us 0.

Comment: Do not use default names for variables . 

Use `len` to display the list length : `print(len(list_name))`

Comment: The method `count` doesn't do what you think it does. Do this instead: `print(len(personlist))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably coming from other languages where `list.count(somelist)` returns the number of elements inside the list. In python, things are a bit different. `list` is a built-in name where you can pass items inside to it and it will create you a `list`. Let's look at `list.count`:

```
Help on method_descriptor:

count(self, value, /)
    Return number of occurrences of value.
```

Ignore the `/` at the end for now. As you can see it returns the number of occurrences of `value` inside `self`. When you call `.count` on a ***list instance*** your instance will be passed as `self` to count method. So you just need to give the `value` as a parameter.

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 1, 1, 3]
>>> my_list.count(1)
3
```

However, when you call `.count` on the `list` itself, Python needs to know about which list you are talking about:

```
>>> list.count(my_list, 1)
3
```

Looking at the way you asked your question, you probably want to know the number of items inside your list. You should use `len` if that's the case

```
>>> len(my_list)
4
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It's a lot clearer to me now!